# Convert rating to percentage in 5 star rating system

Tags: php, math, formulas

I'm having a 5 star rating system in one of my projects. And i would like to convert each star in to percentage value.

This is my database

```
star1

star2

star3

star4

star5

tot_stars

average
```

calculation i use to get rating

```
$cal = ($star1*1 + $star2*2 + $star3*3 + $star4*4 + $star5*5)/$total_stars;

$avg = number_format($cal, 2);
```

What i want to know is what is the math to get each star as a percentage

Example: Yelp.com do this in their website

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your question. You just want to have a percentage value to color a star right?

Comment: wait, what?  why are the 5 stars not just each worth 20%?

Comment: Isn't 1 star 20%, 2 star 40, etc.?

Comment: @Ionic no i want take each rating for the star as a percentage. Ex: if there is 1 x 5 star rating and 1 x 4 star rating each star will have 50% as rating. I hope you understand my question now.

Comment: oh.  so `star1` is the number of one-star ratings.  ok.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes exactly

Comment: One 5 star rating (100%) and one 4 star rating (80%) just average to 90% = 4.5 star rating, right? So if you have three 4 star ratings It's just the avarage = 3*80 and 1*100 =  85% = 4.25 star. I got a feeling you are over-complicating this, unless you mean stars aren't a linearly scale..

Comment: Your column/variable names are not the clearest to me.  I take it that `star1` is the number of one-star ratings, `star2` the number of two-star ratings, and so on.  So is `tot_stars` the cumulative number of stars (so if I give it a 1-star rating and Jim gives it a 2-star rating, `tot_stars` is 3), or the number of ratings (so `tot_stars` is 2)?

Comment: @GolezTrol if one 5 star rating yes it will be 100% but if there one 5 star and one 4 star then each of them should have 50%. i need the percentage counted each star agents the total stars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal is to get the percentage of ratings that are (for example) 1-star, then just divide `star1` by the number of ratings (which I guess is `tot_stars`, although the name seems to imply otherwise). That gets you a proportion; multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

So, for example, letting the database do the math:

```
SELECT star1, star1 * 100 / tot_stars AS percent1, 
       star2, star2 * 100 / tot_stars AS percent2, 
       star3, star3 * 100 / tot_stars AS percent3, 
       star4, star4 * 100 / tot_stars AS percent4, 
       star5, star5 * 100 / tot_stars AS percent5
  FROM starsTable
```

or doing it in PHP:

```
<?php     
// Example data
$star1 = 1;
$star2 = 5;
$star3 = 7;
$star4 = 10;
$star5 = 8;

$tot_stars = $star1 + $star2 + $star3 + $star4 + $star5;

for ($i=1;$i<=5;++$i) {
  $var = "star$i";
  $count = $$var;
  $percent = $count * 100 / $tot_stars;
  for ($j=1;$j<=5;++$j) {
    echo $j <= $i ? "☆ " : "  ";
  }
  printf("\t%2d (%5.2f%%)\n", $count, $percent,2);
}
?>
```

Which outputs this:

```
☆            1 ( 3.23%)
☆ ☆          5 (16.13%)
☆ ☆ ☆        7 (22.58%)
☆ ☆ ☆ ☆     10 (32.26%)
☆ ☆ ☆ ☆ ☆    8 (25.81%)
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution, which is a function, which gets an array, which has the stars as values. We calculate to totalvalues and then calculate the percentage one-by-one. We return the percentages. Each percentage will correspond to the star in the input having the very same index.

```
function getPercentages($inputValues) {
    $totalValues = 0;
    foreach ($inputValues as $inputValue) {
        $totalValues += $inputValue;
    }
    $outputValues = array();
    foreach ($inputValues as $key => $inputValue) {
        $outputValues[$key] = 100 * $inputValue / $totalValues;
    }
    return $outputValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest to do the math in your database and let it return you a float value. This way you can easily display the stars in those "percentage" style.

Example:

```
SELECT (CAST(
          (star1*1) + (star2*2) + (star3)*3 + (star4*4) + (star5*5) 
        as float)/15) as percentageStars
```

Just as an example for your display:

- 5 Stars: 80-100
- 4 Stars: 60-80
- 3 Stars: 40-60
- 2 Stars: 20-40
- 1 Star:  0-20

Due to the fact that you know that 1 star spans 20 Points, you can easily take 1 point as 5% for a fillfactor for the answered star. I think you will try to transform it afterwards to an css property to show the star colored, right?

Example:
You get back a rating of... well lats say 4.8. This means you could just use the full value as total stars, which means 4. Afterwars you can use modulo (`%1`) to get the rest value. This rest value can be multiplied by 100 to get a percentage fill factor for your css for example.

Formula:
`4.8%1 = 0.8 * 100 = 80`

Hopefully this will help you?